# What is the best way to run the same code multiple times in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to run a block of code several times so that all invoices are checked almost instantly and not one after another.

Example: I have a code that fetches the invoices from all the clients in MySQL and loops over them, inside that loop has a logic that consumes an external API and changes the status of the invoice. Suppose I have **10 clients** and each of them has **10 invoices**, the loop will have **100 records** and will follow the customer order, in which case **the 10th customer** will be the last one to have their invoices updated.

How do I make this logic run at the same time for each client?

---

Something similar to this, each block represents a client with its requests being executed / analyzed at the same time, with the same code.

[image]

Comment: You'll either want to look into threading or some other form of parallel execution then. Since threading and asynchronous execution isn't really PHP's default modus operandi, using a queue/worker system with a number of independent workers is often the best choice.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit why this is of importance? Does the processing of the invoices take that long?

Comment: i am agree with @deceze you can have look of RabbitMQ or any alternate solution. Goal is to have background task who wait for "order", if you have 10 workers who wait, you can do 10 orders (or tasks) at the same time. About performance, is always related to your hardware / OS.

Comment: @PaulKertscher The API I use has a time to return the value and if I do not analyze all the invoices on time, the last ones can run out of update, in short, I need a lot to run in parallel.

Comment: @deceze I've heard about the queue / worker in the Laravel framework, have you used it and can you tell me if it really is a good choice?

Comment: I have not and cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Write the code in a script and 
use `popen` for multithreading in PHP.

```
           for ($j=0; $j<10; $j++) 
            {
                $pipe[$j] = popen('script.php', 'mode');
            }

            //Finish thre processes 
            for ($j=0; $j<10; $j++) 
            {
                pclose($pipe[$j]);
            }
```